# ¿Como lle doy formato a una fecha traída de MySQL?

Tags: java

Tengo una fecha almacenada en un `JLabel`, extraída de una consulta en `MySQL` tiene formato `a-m-d` ya probé la función `DATE_FORMAT` y el gestor me dice que no existe esa función, estoy intentando darle el formato `d-m-a` en java con `DateFormat` pero no me sale.

¿Cual es la forma correcta de darle ese formato a la fecha?

Comment: hay una libreria que se llama JCALENDAR quien te hace el cambio de manera automatica.
Despues lo unico que tienes que hacer es el insert con un date y listo

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


    // Toma la fecha y la parsea al formato
    SimpleDateFormat viejoFormato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    // Toma la fecha parseada y la escrib en el formato especificado
    SimpleDateFormat nuevoFormato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Date date = viejoFormato.parse("2016-03-23");
    System.out.println(nuevoFormato.format(date));
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo mejor seria que el motor realice el cambio de formato y luego el lenguaje se encargue solo de mostrarlo. 
Tambien seria recomendable tener en cuenta el formato a la hora de crear la tabla.
Saludos